Minted code box does not break in multiple pages
I'm using tcblisting to format some code, and as the title says this is going overboard instead of breaking in multiple pages, even though I'm using breakable. Could anyone help me? Thanks!
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,breakable,xparse,skins}

\definecolor{bg}{gray}{0.95}
\DeclareTCBListing{mintedbox}{O{}m!O{}}{%
  breakable=true,
  listing engine=minted,
  listing only,
  minted language=#2,
  minted style=default,
  minted options={%
    linenos,
    gobble=0,
    breaklines=true,
    breakafter=,,
    fontsize=\small,
    numbersep=8pt,
    #1},
  boxsep=0pt,
  left skip=0pt,
  right skip=0pt,
  left=25pt,
  right=0pt,
  top=3pt,
  bottom=3pt,
  arc=5pt,
  leftrule=0pt,
  rightrule=0pt,
  bottomrule=2pt,
  toprule=2pt,
  colback=bg,
  colframe=orange!70,
  enhanced,
  overlay={%
    \begin{tcbclipinterior}
    \fill[orange!20!white] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=20pt]frame.north west);
    \end{tcbclipinterior}},
  #3}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Sample code.}
\begin{mintedbox}{python}
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text

\end{mintedbox}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



A figure environment isn't breakable. Don't put your tcolorbox into one if you would like page breaks.
To nevertheless add a caption, you could either use the \captionof{figure}{your text here} macro from the caption package or add it in the title of the tcolorbox as shown in the following example:
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,breakable,xparse,skins}

\definecolor{bg}{gray}{0.95}
\DeclareTCBListing[use counter=figure]{mintedbox}{O{}m!O{}O{}}{%
  breakable=true,
  listing engine=minted,
  listing only,
  minted language=#2,
  minted style=default,
  minted options={%
    linenos,
    gobble=0,
    breaklines=true,
    breakafter=,,
    fontsize=\small,
    numbersep=8pt,
    #1},
  boxsep=0pt,
  left skip=0pt,
  right skip=0pt,
  left=25pt,
  right=0pt,
  top=3pt,
  bottom=3pt,
  arc=5pt,
  leftrule=0pt,
  rightrule=0pt,
  bottomrule=2pt,
  toprule=2pt,
  colback=bg,
  colframe=orange!70,
  enhanced,
  overlay={%
    \begin{tcbclipinterior}
    \fill[orange!20!white] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=20pt]frame.north west);
    \end{tcbclipinterior}},
  title={Figure~\thetcbcounter:~#4},
  #3}

\begin{document}

%\begin{figure}
%\caption{Sample code.}
\begin{mintedbox}{python}[][Sample code]
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
Sample text
\end{mintedbox}
%\end{figure}

\end{document}


Perfect, that works flawlessly. Thanks!

@Merlo You're welcome!
